# Morris Line Chart - X axis showing time (HH:MM) instead of date when there are only 1-6 days

Tags: linechart, morris.js

Good day!

I've been using Morris Line Chart on creating my line graph and I'm currently experiencing some issues on the X-axis which is the date. I've already read and checked the net for any solutions on which I have failed.

In my graph-page, I have a time variable (start_date) on which they are converted to milliseconds using

`var temp_time_i = new Date($scope.start_date *1000);`

Now from this variable, to get the Year, Month and Day and convert them to string, I used

```
var month = ('0' + (temp_time_c.getMonth()+ 1)).slice(-2);
var day = ('0' + temp_time_c.getDate()).slice(-2);
var year = temp_time_c.getFullYear();
```

I then push them in my data array

```
issued.push({ Date: year+"-"+month+"-"+day, Value: response.issued_numbers[a]});
```

note: please ignore the variable a because this  function is inside a for loop.

As you can see, the "Date:" is formatted to year-month-day.However, when I call the chart and the number of days is less than 7, it displays on HH:MM format. You can view the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUljf.png). But when there are more than 7 days on my "Date" variable, it shows the date shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHYGW.png). (Both are imgur files because I am not yet able to upload my own images.

Any help or direct me to a reading is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you set parseTime to false you can use any format.

E.g: `parseTime: false`